# Where can we find the most frequent combination of two Chinese words (搭配)?

Tags: resources

It's quite difficult to correctly use a Chinese word. Sometimes, when I learn a new word, I don't know how to use it in a sentence, what verb to use.

Besides reading more sentences and Chinese texts, is there a website or an online dictionary, where we can find the most frequent combination of two Chinese words 搭配 (verb + noun, noun + adjective etc.)?

Comment: Then what you need is called 词典.  The official one within mainland is 现代汉语词典， but not sure if it has an online version.

Comment: Related: [Is there a dictionary that includes word collocations (词语搭配)?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/31496/is-there-a-dictionary-that-includes-word-collocations-%e8%af%8d%e8%af%ad%e6%90%ad%e9%85%8d)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resources for learning Mandarin Chinese](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/resources-for-learning-mandarin-chinese)

Comment: @dan There is, you can download from app store.

Answer (score 2):

I know there are many excellent learners' dictionaries and collocations dictionaries in English, but sadly Chinese lexicography doesn't seem to have done a good job.

Some resources that might help you:

1）search 汉语搭配词典 here on http://www.ucdrs.superlib.net

2）Look up in general dictionaries

现代汉语词典（download it here [https://b-ok.asia/book/3583521/fc4154）](https://b-ok.asia/book/3583521/fc4154%EF%BC%89)

（台灣）教育部重編國語辭典：http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cbdic/search.htm

learner's dictionary: 《现代汉语八百词》

3）Use 语料库（Corpus）

http://ccl.pku.edu.cn:8080/ccl_corpus/

http://corpus.zhonghuayuwen.org/CnCindex.aspx

http://bcc.blcu.edu.cn/

search 中文 语料库 on Google for more corpora

Answer (score 0):

There are many webpages which will show you example sentences when you enter a phrase.

Start with baidu.com enter:

XX是什么意思？

https://dict.baidu.com/ is baidu's dictionary

and https://fanyi.baidu.com/ is baidu's translator

dict.youdao.com will give you definitions and example sentences for words or phrases.

http://www.iciba.com will translate and has examples of usage.

This dictionary is useful

https://dict.naver.com/linedict/enzhdict/

and

mdbg.net

will take whole sentences or texts and give you English defintions for each character or phrase.

mdbg.net does warn you that the machine segmentation may not always be correct. That is to say, mdbg may not parse the phrases correctly. It may split a phrase which actually belongs together as a word.

Oh, and zdic.net is a nice dictionary too! It has pictures of the old versions of characters.

I'm sure there are many more, but baidu is a good place to start.

You never know if the examples are good Chinese, so you better check.